POCO::Logger writing a comment in the first line of log file
I am using C++-based Docker container and implemented POCO::Logger for logging. And, the logs files are being rotated in every 5 minutes. The POCO::Logger is adding a comment in the first line. I don't want this comment at first line in my log files, how can I get rid of it? Does POCO provides any method/ config to achieve the same?
poco.log:
# Log file created/rotated Friday, 15 Nov 24 11:48:17 GMT
{ "@timestamp":"2024-11-15T11:48:17.490Z","log":{"level":"Information"}, "container":{"name":"testrsk","id":"dlp-testrsk-1.2.500-746f5748cc-mfdz4"}, "labels": {"Description":"Statistical Information Per Event","EventClassID":"EventStats","Severity":"Medium","autoguid":"013e2e4b-0e04-44bc-9ff9-0bf901c80d6d","direction":"read","dlpseverity":"WARNING","eventglobalid":"unknown","failed":"no","source":"[\"dxl://kfk-dev-kafka-0.kfk-dev-kafka-headless.dev-epoeksdatabus.svc.cluster.local:9092,kfk-dev-kafka-1.kfk-dev-kafka-headless.dev-epoeksdatabus.svc.cluster.local:9092,kfk-dev-kafka-2.kfk-dev-kafka-headless.dev-epoeksdatabus.svc.cluster.local:9092/kafka.raw/group0/0\"]","tenant":"0A85E628-EAB7" ,"autoid":8,"dlpeventid":100} }

poco config file:
rsk_logging:
    event:
        level: critical
    message:
        level: information
        rotation: 5minutes
        count: 10
        archive: timestamp
        flush: false
    stats:
        level: information
        rotation: 5minutes
        count: 10
        archive: timestamp
        flush: false
    logfile: /shared/logs/rsk

I don't want comments at the first line in the log files.

No. The rotation message is written unconditionally, at least at the time of writing. You can always edit the code and/or submit a pull request, of course.
